How do I create a Windows User Profile using a Microsoft 365 for business email address?
During the OOBE if I try using a Ms365 for business email address is rejected as not being a valid Microsoft address. Ms365 support told me to use a Microsoft personal email address or a Local profile to get started, then use Access Work or School and add the Ms365 address that way, "Connecting it" using Entra ID. That worked eventually, but now that that user profile exists the Lock Screen no longer shows the original local account that I used. I like having a local admin account as a backup entry into the system. The local account still appears in Other users or Net User but it's not on the lock screen so I cannot figure out how to sign in using that account. Please, someone explain what's going on and tell me how to regain access to the local account.  Thank you.

Here's what worked for me.
First, during the OOBE, create a local admin account. I would name it the same as the username side of the Ms365 email address. Then connect the Work account with it employing Entra ID. Eventually, when you reboot the lock screen will list the Ms365 username and "Other user". Sign in.
The original local account has been subsumed by the work account. So if you still want a local admin account create one now using Settings > Accounts > Other users.
The next time you arrive at the lock screen you will not see the newly created local account. Click on "Other user" and enter into the Email field the local username prefaced with .\ (dot backslash). For example: .\itadmin will log in to the itadmin user profile.
